# Importing a GPX file results in an error that the text encoding of its contents can’t be determined

Tags: ios, swift, gpx

I'm letting users import a GPX file through the following method:

```swift
let documentPickerController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.item"], in: .import)
documentPickerController.allowsMultipleSelection = false
documentPickerController.delegate = self
self.present(documentPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And parsing the selected file as following:

```swift
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
    let firstFileURL = urls[0]
    var outputFileURL: URL? = nil

    let coordinator = NSFileCoordinator()
    var error: NSError? = nil
    coordinator.coordinate(readingItemAt: firstFileURL, options: [], error: &error) { (externalFileURL) -> Void in
        var tempURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
        tempURL.appendPathComponent(externalFileURL.lastPathComponent)
        
        do {
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: tempURL.path) {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: tempURL.path)
            }
            
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(atPath: externalFileURL.path, toPath: tempURL.path)
            outputFileURL = tempURL
        } catch {
            print("File operation error: " + error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    guard let path = outputFileURL?.path else { return }
    
    do {
        let content = try String(contentsOfFile: path) // error here
        let data = content.data(using: .utf8)
        let parser = XMLParser.init(data: data!)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

But, I'm getting the following error message:

> couldn’t be opened because the text encoding of its contents can’t be determined.

I thought maybe it was the way I was importing the files so I tried changing `public.item` to following:

```swift
let types = UTType.types(tag: "gpx", tagClass: UTTagClass.filenameExtension, conformingTo: nil)
let documentPickerController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: types, in: .import)
documentPickerController.allowsMultipleSelection = false
documentPickerController.delegate = self
self.present(documentPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and modifying the info.plist as explained in this [article](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-fix-greyed-icons-on-ios-document-browser-and-picker-8dea8a76d6e7).

But then, none of the GPX files become selectable and turn grey from within the document picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're absolutely right. This expression is just wrong:

```
String(contentsOfFile: path)
```

You could specify the encoding by adding an `encoding:` parameter.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/init(contentsoffile:encoding:)

But don't. Don't use `String(contentsOfFile:)` at all. Don't use file paths at all. Use *file URLs*. Given a file URL, read from it with `String(contentsOf:encoding:)`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/init(contentsof:encoding:)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
let type = UTType(filenameExtension: "gpx")!
var documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController!
let supportedTypes: [UTType] = [type]
documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: supportedTypes)
documentPicker.delegate = self
documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = false
documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
self.present(documentPicker, animated: true)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).